# OpenCV / EmguCV capping at 255 even though image depth is UInt16

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm creating an image object in C# using EmguCV with depth UInt16 (ushort).
Then I'm filling in the image with a linear gradient that increases in value the higher the row index.

What I don't understand is, that the value 255 produces 100% white pixels. But I've specified a depth of 16 bits which, to my understanding, should use 65,535 to represent white. What I've found is that everything greater than or equal to 255 is white.

```
var image = new Image<Gray, UInt16>(255, 255);
for (int column = 0; column < image.Width; column++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < image.Height; row++)
    {
        image.Data[row, column, 0] = (UInt16)row;
    }
}
image.Save("temp.jpg");
```

Unexpected result:

[image: Gradient]

What am I missing? How can I create an image and fill it with values from 0 - 65,535 that actually map to 0 being black and 65,535 being white?

Comment: Save in PNG.I don't think JPEG handles 16 bit depth images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was saving in JPG format which does not support 16 bits. PNG does.

Thank you Miki for your [helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332123/opencv-emgucv-capping-at-255-even-though-image-depth-is-uint16?noredirect=1#comment79625368_46332123).